# The problem with the transition from JSP to Tomcat 7 servlet. The post method is not called from JSP page

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat7

**I have a jsp page index.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<fmt:setLocale value="${locale}" scope="session"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="local.pagecontent"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:redirect url="/controller?command=go_to_login_page"/>
    <h1>dd</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**A command is executed that redirects to the next page**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%--
<fmt:setLocale value="${locale}" scope="session" />
--%>
<fmt:setBundle basename="local.pagecontent"/>

<html>
<head>
    <title><fmt:message key="login.title"/></title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="middle">
    <h1>Employee Login Form</h1>
    <form name="loginForm"  method="get" action="controller">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="login"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Login</td>
                <td><label>
                    <input type="text" name="login" />
                </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" />
                </label></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <button type="submit">sign in</button>
        <a href="registration.jsp">No account?</a>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**In it, I enter my username and password, and click on the submit button. I looked in the debug that the data does not go to the servlet, I am redirected to a page with the address**

`http://localhost:8094/course_war_exploded/pages/controller?command=login&login=mylogin&password=mypassword`

**My web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/errors/exception_error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <!--<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.course.controller.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>-->

    <!--<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>controller</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>-->

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

**And the servlet itself. You can see my attempts to figure out what's going on.**

```
    @WebServlet(name = "ControllerServlet", value = "/controller")
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String stringCommand = request.getParameter(RequestParameter.COMMAND);
        Command command = CommandProvider.defineCommand(stringCommand).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
/*
        Command = new CreateAccountCommand();
*/
        System.out.println(stringCommand + "--------");
        try {
            Router router = command.execute(request);
            System.out.println(router.getPage());
            System.out.println(router.getType().name());
            switch (router.getType()) {
                case FORWARD -> request.getRequestDispatcher(router.getPage()).forward(request, response);
                case REDIRECT -> response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + router.getPage());
                default -> {
                    logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Router type {} is incorrect", router.getType());
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + PagePath.ERROR_404);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | ServletException | ServiceException | ControllerException e) {
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Error when executing command {} ", stringCommand);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(EXCEPTION, e);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + PagePath.EXCEPTION_ERROR_REDIRECT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to get your question reopened, try to write a better title, reduce the code samples to the necessary MRE [How to create a **M**inimal, **R**eproducible **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and finish the post with an actual question

Answer (score 1):

Your question resumes to: *I looked in the debug that the data does not go to the servlet, I am redirected to a page with the address ...*

This is due to the difference of "GET" and "POST" methods.

in your code, the form action method is GET, which leads to the string you are reporting:
`http://localhost:8094/course_war_exploded/pages/controller?command=login&login=mylogin&password=mypassword`

the POST method is slightly different, instead of appending a string with the form data to the URL it sends a POST array to your controller, which you than can read in.

so in your case change form method to:

```
<form name="loginForm"  method="post" action="controller.jsp">
```